# MikTex installation problem

Tags: luatex, miktex, installing, miktex2.9

Following a bug during a Windows update of my computer, I had to reset it to factory settings and empty all its memory. So I also had to reinstall MikTeX on my computer. I proceeded as usual but now MikTex does not allow me to compile with LuaLaTex.

So I uninstalled/reinstalled MikTeX several times according to the procedure described on the official MikTex website, but the problem persists.

Sometimes (not always), during installation I get the following error message :
[image]

And

```
miktex conversion from UTF-8 yte sequence to wide character string did not succeed
```

As indicated, once MikTeX is installed, I immediately update MikTeX directly from the console.

Then, in any case, I try to compile very simple files (with TeXwork or TeXmaker), with PDFLaTeX it works, but not with LuaLaTeX. I get the following log file :

```
2020-04-04 13:05:02,708+0200 INFO  miktex-luatex - starting with command line: "F:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\miktex-luatex.exe" -synctex=1 --fmt=lualatex Test.tex
2020-04-04 13:05:02,786+0200 INFO  miktex-luatex - going to create file: lualatex.fmt
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 ERROR miktex-luatex - F:\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\initexmf.exe did not succeed; exitCode: 1
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 ERROR miktex-luatex - output:
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 ERROR miktex-luatex - 
Sorry, but "MiKTeX Configuration Utility" did not succeed for the following reason:

  Unknown format name/engine: lualatex/luatex

The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:

  C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf.log

2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 FATAL miktex-luatex - The memory dump file could not be found.
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 FATAL miktex-luatex - Info: fileName="lualatex.fmt"
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 FATAL miktex-luatex - Source: Programs\TeXAndFriends\luatex\miktex\miktex.cpp
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 FATAL miktex-luatex - Line: 74
2020-04-04 13:05:03,098+0200 INFO  miktex-luatex - finishing with exit code 1
```

In this period of confinement and teleworking, this problem comes at the worst possible time! I work a lot with files using LuaLaTeX and I can't afford to fall behind on my work.

I really need your help. Thank you in advance. John

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! It seems you should build the lualatex format. Try to build  it directly from MiKTeX console (`Settings` tab) *before* you try to compile whatever.

Comment: Can you run your document from the command line (`lualatex mydoc` assuming your file is called `mydoc.tex`)? Can you show us the screenshots of your editor configurations for LuaLaTeX, please?

Comment: That is quite certainly a side-effect of the change from luatex to luahbtex for the lualatex format. miktex shouldn't try to run miktex-luatex but should use miktex-luahbtex. But to sort this out you need to provide a few more infos about your settings.

Comment: Hello @Bernard, this is what I did but I have still have the same problem. I built LuaLaTeX format and LuaTeX format. For LuaTeX format I had this error message : The MiKTeX configuration utility failed for some reason. The process output has been saved to a file.

Details:
fileName="C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex/bin/x64\initexmf.exe", exitCode="1",
savedOutput="C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\initexmf_2020-04-04-144328.out"

Comment: @moewe Are you talking about AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX2.9\miktex\bin\x64\lualatex.exe ? Where can I find information about the editor configurations for LuaLaTeX ?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer what sort of informations do you need ?

Comment: It is a bug that your TeX editor invokes `miktex-luatex`. As Ulrike has pointed out, it should invoke `miktex-luahbtex` instead. Workaround for TeXworks: `Edit / Preferences... / Typesetting` and for each LuaLaTeX based tool replace `miktex-luatex.exe` with `miktex-luahbtex.exe`.

Comment: No better do what Christian says, he is right, it is texworks that refers to the wrong binary.

Comment: @ChristianSchenk Tank you ! It seems to works fine with TeXworks. Do you know how to do that with TeXmaker. I went to `Option->Configure Texmaker->Commands` but from there I don't know what to do, it's quite different from the TeXworks interface.

Comment: I think I spoke too soon. I tried to compile one of my documents and this is the error I get: `This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (MiKTeX 2.9.7380 64-bit) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
("./Tables with Latex.tex" LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5                           Undefined control sequence. l.1 \documentclass                                                    
Undefined control sequence. l.3 \usepackage`                                      etc...